# Using Matlab to get maximum values from many polyfitted curves in one figure

Tags: matlab

```matlab
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
z1 = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 36, 25, 16, 8, 1];
z2 = [1, 5, 10, 17, 26, 38, 26, 17, 10, 9, 7, 1];
z3 = [1, 8, 18, 30, 40, 30, 18, 8, 7, 4, 3, 1];  
plot(x, z1, '*');
hold on;

p1 = polyfit(x, z1, 5);
z1fit = polyval(p1, x);
plot(x, z1fit);
hold on;

plot(x, z2, '*');
p2 = polyfit(x, z2, 5);
z2fit = polyval(p2, x);
plot(x, z2fit);
hold on;

plot(x, z3,'*');
p3 = polyfit(x, z3, 5);
z3fit = polyval(p3, x);
plot(x, z3fit);
```

My question is, how to find every maximum value of each curve and display them? The maximum points are not the maximum values that I gave , It should be the peak points after fitting. I can simply read these peak points from the plotted figure, just want to know how to get the exact coordinate of the highest peak of the polynomial fit and return them. The degree of n (in my code 5) from `polyfit` is changeable.

Comment: Is it not just `[maxValue, xOfMax] = max(z1fit)`?

Comment: No, I have tried this way, there are no return values, But THX all the same.

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact value of the maximum in the range of `x`, you can use the optimization toolbox.

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
z1=[1,4,9,16,25,36,49,36,25,16,8,1];
p1=polyfit(x, z1, 5);
fun = @(x) -polyval(p1,x);
x_max = fminbnd(fun,x(1),x(end))

figure; hold on;
plot(x,z1,'*');
fplot(@(x) polyval(p1,x),[x(1) x(end)],':');
plot(x_max,polyval(p1,x_max),'o');
legend('data','fit','max')
```

[image]

Use the [polyfit](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html) function to get the coefficients of the fitted polynomial, use the [polyval](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html) function to create a function handle to the polynomial you created and the [fminbnd](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminbnd.html) to "Find minimum of single-variable function on fixed interval". With the function handle, you can use the [fplot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html) function to plot the fit.

Edit:

If you want to calculate and plot the fitted curves in the same figure, you can:

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
z1 = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 36, 25, 16, 8, 1];
z2 = [1, 5, 10, 17, 26, 38, 26, 17, 10, 9, 7, 1];
z3 = [1, 8, 18, 30, 40, 30, 18, 8, 7, 4, 3, 1];

z = [z1;z2;z3];

figure; hold on;
for ii=1:size(z,1)
    p1=polyfit(x, z(ii,:), 5);
    fun = @(x) -polyval(p1,x);
    x_max = fminbnd(fun,x(1),x(end))

    plot(x,z(ii,:),'*');
    fplot(@(x) polyval(p1,x),[x(1) x(end)],':');
    plot(x_max,polyval(p1,x_max),'o');
end
```

The result, however, will not be that good, because you will have a lot of information in the same figure. Depending on what you want, that may be good. But I suggest you plot on different figures different data, maybe using subplots.
[image]

Comment: THX so much, BUT  another questions, When I want to return the values of Z, how would I change the code? And when there are a lot of Z,e.g from Z1 to Z9, I just need to repeat and change the corresponding code? or there is another way to simplify this process.           THX again!

Comment: To get the correspondent z value, just call the function with 2 output arguments: `[x_max,z_max] = fminbnd(___)` To do it for different data points from `z1` to `z9`, just repeat it. If you store z1 to z9 in a cell array, then a for-loop can do the trick

Comment: super thanks! But if I want to plot the curves from z1 to z9 in only one figure, how should I do it?  The for-loop just makes different figures with different curves.

Comment: write the `figure` outside the for loop and use the [`hold on`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) to plot on the same figure

Comment: `for i=1:a %The number of rows in a matrix including z1 z2 z3
 x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
 z1=a(i,:);
 p1=polyfit(x, z1, 5);
 fun = @(x) -polyval(p1,x);
 x_max = fminbnd(fun,x(1),x(end))
 y1_max=polyval(p1, x_max)
end
figure; hold on;
 plot(x,z1,'*');
 fplot(@(x) polyval(p1,x),[x(1) x(end)],':');
 plot(x_max,polyval(p1,x_max),'o');
 legend('data','fit','max');`      you mean like this?

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you how to plot the different curves in one figure

Comment: OK， I got it THX